# Django models: database design for user and follower

Tags: django, postgresql, model, psql

In Django model I am making a table 'followers', which has:

```
user's id. (this is followed by)
user's id (this is follower)
```

that's simple a user can follow other users.

How should I define the model in Django?

I tried this, but does not work:

```
user = models.ForeignKey('self')
follower_id = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

How should this be done?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'self' argument won't work unless you have a model called `self`.

Assuming that your assignment model is called `Following`, and you're using the built in `User` model then you can do:

```
class Following(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='followers')
    follower = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='targets')
```

This will likely need some further uniqueness and validation logic.

Note the `related_name` attribute, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name. This means that for a given user object you can do `user.targets.all()` to get users they follow, and `user.followers.all()` to get users who follow them.

Note also that Django returns target model instances, not IDs, in the ORM. This means that even though the underlying table may be called `follower_id`, in the python code `following.follower` will return an actual User object.

Comment: I did this..but I get this error:

main.followers.follower_id: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'followers.follower_id' clashes with reverse accessor for 'followers.user'.
 HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'followers.follower_id' or 'followers.user'.

Comment: Ah, yes. Django creates reverse relationships, so that you can follow the relationship backwards. I have amended my answer to add the `related_name` attribute.

Comment: I also notice from your traceback above that your table is called `Followers`. It's a small thing, but convention is to use singular nouns for class names. I went with `Following` as an object of this class represents a _following_ by one user of another user. Naming things is hard though, and this isn't the easiest one to encapsulate.

Comment: Inside an instantiated class, `self` (the name, not `'self'` the string) returns the current instance. To refer to the model you could do `self.__class__`. You could also see the contenttypes framework for other ways of achieving this. However, here you want to refer to the User model, not recursively to this Following/Followers model.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as `Following` is actually the [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) table for the many-to-many relationship between Users. I would create a `Profile` model which extends the Django `User` model, and then declare the many-to-many relationship (using `ManyToManyField`).

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='followers')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the many to many field.

`followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False)`