# Following each other django model

Tags: django

I want to build model to follow each other, 
I tried to folow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069192/django-models-database-design-for-user-and-follower)

But I'm facing some error.

[image]

```
class InstagramBot(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.CharField(verbose_name='Email', max_length=55)
    ............
```

and another model is here

```
class Following(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey(InstagramBot, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='followers_set')
    follower = models.ForeignKey(InstagramBot, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='targets_set')
```

Here i want to make sure that,

```
-> same bot cannot follow itself

-> same bot cannot follow other bots multiple times

-> I want to get list of all the bot with number of followers 

-> I want to get list of all the bot which is not followed by a bot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`followers_set` can be accessed by an instance. So you need to get an instance first then use `followers_set` with that instance.

```py
obj = InstagramBot.objects.first() # or some other instance by query.
# then you can use the reverse lookup
obj.followers_set.all() # will get all the objects from Following table.
```

Now the other questions:

**1. same bot cannot follow itself** 
create a new function/method (static function or manager method) and check if the `target_id` and `follower_id` is same conditions.

```py
class Following(models.Model):
    # fields

    def create_follower(user_id, follower_id):
        if user_id == follower_id:
            return
```

There are plenty of ways to check this condition, use the one which serves your purpose.

**2. same bot cannot follow other bots multiple times** 
You can use [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) to provide unique constraint for 2 column.

```py
class Following(models.Model):
    # fields
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'follower'], name='unique follower')
    ]
```

or You can call [validate_unique()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.validate_unique) from your save method and perform your custom logic to check if row with same value already exists.

**3. I want to get list of all the bot with number of followers**
You can use annotate for that.

```py
from django.db.models import Count

data = InstagramBot.objects.annotate(f_count=Count('followers_set'))
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but I've also another requirements that is, I want to get list of all the bot which not following certain bot