# Having trouble wrapping my head around follower/target models in Models.py

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have just started with making a similar site to Pinterest and the site has follower/target system that I have barely any understanding of. So far, my models.py code is below:

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    username    = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True)
    email       = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    password    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    nickname    = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True)
    target      = models.ManyToManyField(self, through='Follow')
    follower    = models.ManyToManyField(self, through='Follow')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'

class Follow(models.Model):
    follower    = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='targets')
    target      = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='followers')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'follows'
```

This code was made with reference to another StackOverflow thread
[Django models: database design for user and follower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069192/django-models-database-design-for-user-and-follower)
However, I am having trouble understanding how using "related_name='targets' in 'follower' and "related_name='followers'" in 'target' where I can't see any 'targets'(plural) or 'followers'(plural) in other areas of models.py

Should I get rid of that related_name, since there is no such table called "followers" or "targets"? And if you spot major errors in my code or logic, can you tell me? Thanks!

Comment: `related_name` means that Django adds a relation to the other model, so you can get the related `Follow` objects that are referenced with `target` through `myuser.followers`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I get rid of that `related_name`, since there is no such table called `followers` or `targets`.

There is never a table named `followers` or `targets`. The [**`related_name`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name) is a *conceptual* relation Django makes to the other model (in this case `User`). It means that for a `User` object `myuser`, you can access the `Follow` objects that refer to that user through `target` for example with `myuser.followers.all()`, so:

```
Follow.objects.filter(target=myuser)
```

is equivalent to:

```
myuser.followers.all()
```

The default of a `related_name` is `modelname_set`, so here that would be `follow_set`. But if you remove both `related_name`s, then that would result in a name conflict, since one can not add two relations `follow_set` to the `User` model (and each having a different semantical value).

> if you spot major errors in my code or logic, can you tell me?

The problem is that since `ManyToManyField`s refer to `'self`' (it should be `'self'` as string literal), it is ambigous what the "source" and what the target will be, furthermore Django will assume that the relation is [**`symmetrical`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical), which is not the case. You should specify what the source and target foreign keys are, you can do that with the [**`through_fields=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields). It furthermore is better to simply define the `related_name` of the `ManyToManyField` in reverse, to avoid duplicated logic.

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    follows = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        through='Follow',
        symmetrical=False,
        related_name='followed_by',
        through_fields=('follower', 'target')
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'

class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='targets'
    )
    target = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='followers'
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'follows'
```

Here a `User` object `myuser` can thus access `myuser.follows.all()` to access all the users that they follow, `myuser.followed_by.all()` is the set of `User`s that follow `myuser`. `myuser.targets.all()` is the set of `Follow` objects that he is following, and `myuser.followers.all()` is the set of `Follow` objects that are following that user.